# iOS : counting tap inside subview

Tags: ios, class, subviews

In my app, every time a user draw a circle, it alloc/init a circle UIView, and draw a circle on the screen. now every time the user is tapping the circle an image of a number is changing.
i would like that when a circle is created with the number one for example,  the next circle that will be created, and the user will double tap it will show directly  the image of number two instead.

Comment: uitapgesturerecognizer use

Comment: i use it to switch the images, but how can i share the count so every circle will know what is the number